# How to expand a Webix tree node automatically when elements added to the tree

Tags: javascript, webix

In my Webix application , I have a tree with some nodes and leaf nodes to them.
If any additional node or leaf node get added to the main branch or to any sub-branch, I want to automatically refresh that part of the tree (may be by expanding the node) from an external .js file.

I have a snippet here: https://webix.com/snippet/2caca842

Any example of how can I write the expand function will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If I have the treeObject in let's say var treeObj , then by doing treeObj._htmlmap, I am getting all the ids of the tree. Also by treeObj._viewobj.textContent I get all the textual name of each node. Is there a way to get the mapping of node names and their corresponding ids from the treeObj ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting what exactly your problem statement is, But, if you want the complete information of the nodes,their mapping with parents, their parent ids etc... you can use `instance.data.pull`, which will be giving you the complete information of all the rows and columns. where `instance` is the instance of the component{tree, datatable, treetable, whatever component of webix you are using}.

you can do `this.data.pull` inside the `onBeforeOpen` event you will get result as

```
1: {id: "1", open: false, value: "Chicago", $parent: "root", $level: 2, …}
1.1: {id: "1.1", value: "Houston", $parent: "1", $level: 3, $count: 0}
1.2: {id: "1.2", value: "San Diego", $parent: "1", $level: 3, $count: 0}
2: {id: "2", value: "States", open: true, $parent: "root", $level: 2, …}
2.1: {id: "2.1", value: "California", $parent: "2", $level: 3, $count: 0}
2.2: {id: "2.2", value: "Florida", $parent: "2", $level: 3, $count: 0}
root: {id: "root", value: "Cities", open: true, $parent: 0, $level: 1, …}
```

where `root` will be the parent element, `$level` represents at which level this element is present, `open` represent whether the current element is open or close.

Comment: What you provided is really helpful. From this I know the id of 'Houston' is 1.1. Let's assume Houston also has leaf nodes, and I added one more leaf node to it as 'abcd'. Now after adding when I am again refreshing/expanding the Houston node, it does get expanded but also the existing nodes under 'Houston' is getting re-created. So I get all the leaf nodes under 'Houston' twice. Same problem will happen for every other node. If you can help me on that by refreshing the tree/node  with the newly added/deleted one would be great. May be a small exmaple.

Comment: I am not getting that how the node can be created twice automatically, if you are creating it once. Could you please more elaborate or show the code snippet?

Comment: Give me sometime so that I can elaborate it better. Thanks

Comment: Everytime I add something to the data store, I am calling treeobj.data.add(obj,index,parentId). Just taking care that after the inital load, whenever I add any extra node only that is getting added through treeobj.data.add(obj,index,parentId) by iterating on the array of new nodes added. However, if I delete any node then the array is empty hence nothing to iterate on and show. If you could show me an example of just to refresh the existing tree would be great.

Comment: I am not getting that why you are adding the new rows to data Array yourself, you should use the webix api to add the row, because its the responsibility of the api, to add or remove the rows. If you want to add the elements yourself then you should call the refresh() explicitly, after adding or removing the element. Please follow the below link, I am adding/removing the elements using webix api.  `https://webix.com/snippet/00800a0f`

Comment: In case you still find any issues, feel free to ask.

Comment: The add/rem you showed is fine. However for me add is working, but when I remove, before that the data is already removed from my database, so the tree.remove(id) says no such id existing. I basically need to refresh the part of the tree by providing the root node. Lets amongst many root nodes, I know to which root node data got added/removed. Can I refresh the tree with that root node id. That would just simply do my job. Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: You can remove the element only if the element is visible on UI, because webix generate the DOM for only those elements which are visible at the moment.  This might be the case with you, you might be deleting the elements, which is not visible on the UI. If this is not the case, you can share your code, I can check.

Comment: As I told you how am I trying to call expand node post the save & delete operation and the delete is not working as it is already deleted from the UI. Now after the save/delete, I am calling the collapse with the id of the node and then triggering the onBeforeOpen with the id as tree.callEvent('onBeforeOpen, [id]), so that after the save/delete operation the tree node auto collapse&expand. The expand event is getting called properly, however it is not able auto-expand the node ('+' sign). When I click on it I see double items. What could be the way to refresh considering my case?

Comment: sorry, I am not getting your issue, could you please share the code, so that I can check.